# Where can I buy a basic non-smart monochrome phone online? (long battery life)

Tags: mobile-phone, battery-life

I am looking for a basic phone, to make calls and sens/receive SMS.

Nothing more - all else is battery drain, and I am looking for the longest battery life that I can find.

To that end, I am looking for a monochrome screen, if such a thing is still manufactured.

Years back, I remember that Sharp made a line of long battery life phones. Now they don't make phones (if they are even still in business).

I have fond memories of a small, grey, rubberized Nokia - was it an N45? - with a screen barely an inch in diagonal (just three lines of display), and I'd be glad of something similar.

I don't need Daul SIM, Wifi, BlueTooth, GPS, color screen, radio, not even music player; just calls & texts (and those will be few, and far between).

Can anyone recommend soemthing that can be bought online?

[This question](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/256/mobile-phone-used-only-for-calls-sms?rq=1) looked good, but it is looking for Dual SIM, which I do not require.

---

[Update] Nokia are [relaunching the 3310](http://www.vanguardngr.com/2017/02/nokia-3310-makes-a-comback/). 100 hours standby for Eur 59

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Amazon.com

[5200mAh Long Standby Rugged Mobile Phone with Waterproof Shockproof Dustproof Unlocked Phone for Elderly People Adventurers Army Cellphone(Black)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01CDUBEMC)

It's $50, and can call and send/receive sms. 5200mAh battery w./ 72 hours talk time and 360 hours standby (as the manufacturer claims). I'm pretty sure the screen is color though.